# Objective C Expected ';'after method prototype error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I have a problem with my code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol ServiceDelegate <NSObject>


-(void)serviceFinished:(id)service withError:(BOOL)error {
    if (!error)
        [searchResults removeAllObjects];

        for (NSDictionary *movie in [service results]) {
            [searchResults addObject:[movie valueForKey:@"title"]];
        }

        [[self tableView] reloadData];
    }


@end
```

it keeps telling me to put a ; instead of { in this line

```
-(void)serviceFinished:(id)service withError:(BOOL)error {
```

however If i replace the { then the code breaks and doesn't work. and tells me that the second line of code

```
if (!error) {
```

the if has the error "Expected identifier or '('

any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: Find a newer tutorial.

Comment: everything ive searched utilises storyboard or swift.... I dont want that

Comment: What's happening with the code you have now? Is the text just not displaying?

Comment: I think your code has wrong {}.For me, t - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath does not have correct {}. And - (id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style also has same problem.

Comment: For adding the title to the table, It says use of undeclared identifier initWithStyle, Also I don't know where in the code I should put it.

Comment: Try putting the title in the `- (id) init` constructor instead.

Comment: that gives me the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interface code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FilmTableViewController : UITableViewController

@end

@interface initWithStyle : NSString
- (void)UITableViewStyle:(NSString*);

@end
```

is ***wrong***. It should be:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FilmTableViewController : UITableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style;

@end
```

`@interface` should always be followed by the **class name** -and, if applicable, `:` and the superclass name, and adopted protocols inside angled brackets (and separated by commas)-. The interface declaration for **methods** is the same as the function header in the implementation (definition), with a semicolon (`;`) at the end (same rule as for C functions, but must be withing the `@interface...` / `@end` pair.)

**Addendum:** You mentioned that iti is the .m file that seems to be causing the error; However, your method definition of `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style` looks OK... So, which line does Xcode point to? What is the actual error message?

**Addendum 2:** You are missing a closing `}` between the method body of `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `initWithStyle:` (right after `return cell;`), that is why the compiler isn't interpreting the method definition as proper code. Your code is broken.

Comment: still says that initWithStyle is undeclared

Comment: are you calling it as an instance method, on an object of type  `FilmTableViewController` , within a file that has `#import  "FilmTableViewController.h"`?

Comment: Remember, `initWithStyle:` and `initWithStyle` (no params) are treated as different methods. Arguments aren't optional.

Comment: @ Nicolas, Im not too sure, i'm trying to follow my university tutorial but it seems to have missed out declaring functions.

Comment: Please edit your question, and add the code that is causing the error (where you actually call the method).

Comment: Ive pasted the the whole code, but the part that was causing the problem was the .M extract I posted originally.

Comment: the line it points to is

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style

and after using the amended interface code you provided, the error code is still use of undeclared identifier ínitWithStyle'

Comment: thank you so much for the help, The tutorial I'm using isn't the best and I didn't think of looking for the closing }.